# Check User Visit the Url in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx, next-router

I want to check the if visit the page first time the function run else not run

e.g.:

very first time user open the site HOME page show the condition is must run after the user visit /about page the about page also first time condition run after this user again back to the home page the home page is visited the condition is not run for this time how can I achieve this in next.js

`import useScrollPosition from "/hooks/useScrollPosition";`

```
const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();
const [isShowComponents, setIsShowComponents] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
if (scrollPosition >= 100) {
  setIsShowComponents(true);
 }
}, [scrollPosition]);



{isShowComponents ? (
      <>
        <WorkWithUs />
        <Team />
        <FAQS />
      </>
    ) : <BaseSkeleton />}
```

**This condition is just run when user very first time on the page.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Lets I have a condition that: if user enter first time then only, and only I want to show only two components after some scroll he is able to see the another components, but this is must be just first time when he visits another page and after again revisit the home page the no condition is run this time. Hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not tried it by my own but you can try something like this
save the paths visited on localStorage or in cookies in each Component

**Home Component**

```js
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom"
import {useState,useEffect} from "react"
const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();
const [isShowComponents, setIsShowComponents] = useState(false);

const Home = ()=>{
   const location =useLocation()
   const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();
   const [path, setPath] = useLocalStorage("home","");
   

   useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("home"))
      if(!localStorage.getItem("home")){
        localStorage.setItem("home",location.pathname)
      }else{
         setIsShowComponents(true);
      }   
   },[])
    useEffect(() => {
      if (scrollPosition >= 100 && !localStorage.getItem("home")) {
         setPath(localStorage.getItem("home"))
      }
    }, [scrollPosition]);
  return <h1>{path}</h1>
}
```

---

**APP Component**

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
     <Router>
       <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
         <Route exact path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
         <Route exact path="/work" element={<Work/>}/>
         <Route exact path="/setting" element={<Setting/>}/>
       </Routes>
     </Router>
    </>
  );
};
```

**This will be more Good if we will make this functionality in customHook**